# Exchange Online group Creation using powershell use .onmicrosoft.com domain

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying create a group using **PowerShell** and it create a group with **.onmicrosoft.com** domain rather than custom domain.

If I create group from Exchange Portal, it works fine.

help will be appreciated.

**Powershell Output:**

```
PS F:\Tools\PowerShell Script\O365AdminTasks> New-DistributionGroup
        -Name $ExchangeGroup -Alias $ExchangeGroup -Type $ExchangeGroupType

Name  DisplayName GroupType PrimarySmtpAddress                  
----  ----------- --------- ------------------                  
Test1 Test1       Universal Test1@systemsemail.onmicrosoft.com
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will be creating office 365 Dl with details

```
 New-DistributionGroup -Name <DL name> -DisplayName <DL display name> -Alias <Alias> -PrimarySmtpAddress <Email Address>


New-DistributionGroup -Name Atest -DisplayName Atest -Alias atest -PrimarySmtpAddress atest@systemsemail.onmicrosoft.com
```